# Is a number of type never?

Tags: typescript

A small snippet of code is breaking my head:

```
   var label: number= 12354;
   if(typeof(label) == 'number'){
      label =label.toString();
   }
```

But it's giving an error in toString: The property 'toString' does not exist in type 'never'. But it is a number! Why does inside if say it is of type never? If you change label to type any, the errors will be eliminated. I want to know why typescript ignored validation and stated something impossible in the presented context?

```
    //Expectation
    label = '12345';
    //Reality:
     Property 'toString' does not exist in type 'never'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: I don't get the same error... https://tsplay.dev/w6Qa6W

Comment: I wonder if OP's linter sees that `label` is of type `number`, but that it's also being assigned a `string` value, and so is trying to find the common type between them (which there is none)?

Comment: @yshavit: This is in the middle of the code. I know the type of the input (it is similar to this one and checked the type) so the validation would be for something else (redirection). But the typescript is forcing you to put everything as any. I tried to use typescript to have security in the code, but it's causing more headaches. Label is a number (0, 12, 365, 556...). By ensuring that it is a number, how does it suddenly become never? Before I used an array that is of type never, but it is not even used in the code!

Comment: @katniss: So it is! I do not understand. It seems that typescript gives this error in the middle of a project. This is a simple validation in the middle of the code. And it's giving this error!!! If you doubt even 2 + 2 it will be equal to 1236654... I don't know, but something is interfering and I have no idea what it is

Comment: You are trying to assign a string to a number there... label is already typed to 'number'.  So when you do label = label.toString();... it's causing an issue for Typescript.  (It's a 'number' type, never a string.)  The error is a little odd, but you should be able to do: let stringlabel = label.toString();

Comment: In the tsplay link that @katniss pasted above, if you add `console.log(label)` so that it doesn't complain about an unused var, you instead get an error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)`. So I'm guessing that something in your system — a different version of typescript, a linter, or your IDE — is handling it slightly differently. Instead of assuming that the type is `number` and erroring that it can't be assigned a string, it's assuming that the type is "whatever type can be either a number or a string". That can't happen, so it's (weirdly) treating it as `never`.

Comment: But if you want to dig into it more, we'll need more info: what version of typescript you're using, any linters, IDE, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
var label: number | string = 12354;

if (typeof label === 'number') {
  label = label.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Do you know why typescript saw this as type never? I thought this only appeared when working with arrays